# $\left | p(z_{0}) \right | = \inf \left \{ \left | p(z) \right | : z \in \mathbb{C} \right \} $

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, compactness

Using only Proposition (1) and a compactness argument, WITHOUT The fundamental theorem of algebra, show that there is a point $z_{0}$ such that
$$\left | p(z_{0}) \right | = \inf \left \{ \left | p(z) \right | : z \in \mathbb{C} \right \} $$.

Proposition (1):

$$ p(z) = a_{0} + a_{1}z + ... +a_{n}z^{n}$$ with $a_{n} \neq 0 $. Then
$$ \frac{p(z)}{a_{n}z^{n}} \rightarrow  1 $$ for $z\rightarrow \infty$

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write proposition, I´ve added it.

Comment: From the limit you get that there is $M$ such that for all $z$ satisfying $|z|>M$ you have $|p(z)/(a_nz^n)-1|<1/2$. It follows that for those $z$ we have $1/2>|p(z)/(a_nz^n)-1|\leq 1-|p(z)|/(|a_n||z|^n$. So, $|p(z)|/(|a_n||z|^n)>|a_n||z|^n/2\geq |a_n||M|^n/2$. You can take $M$ even larger such that $|a_n||M|^n/2>|p(0)|$. Therefore, the infimum of $|p(z)|$ is not going to be in $|z|>M$. It will have to happen in the compact set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ |z|\leq M\}$. Since $|p(z)|$ is continuous on $|z|\leq M$ is attains its infimum there.